# Colorizing a specific graph when it is using in an optimization model

Tags: python, colors, networkx, mathematical-optimization

I am working on an optimization model that uses a directed graph to illustrate a specific network. After the optimization is terminated, I am willing to colorize this graph based on the output of the optimization model. Let's say, there is a directed graph in the following form:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(
[(0, 1),
(1, 2), (1, 3), 
(2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), 
(3, 6), (3, 7), 
(4, 9), 
(5, 9), 
(6, 8),
(7, 11),
(8, 9), (8, 10),
(9, 12),
(10, 12),
(11, 10),
(12, 13),
])
```

After solving the model the output is something like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Station:  1
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
operation  0     is being assigned to the station
operation  1     is being assigned to the station
operation  2     is being assigned to the station
operation  3     is being assigned to the station
operation  5     is being assigned to the station
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Station:  2
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
operation  6     is being assigned to the station
operation  8     is being assigned to the station
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Station:  3
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
operation  4     is being assigned to the station
operation  7     is being assigned to the station
operation  9     is being assigned to the station
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Station:  4
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
operation  10    is being assigned to the station
operation  11    is being assigned to the station
operation  12    is being assigned to the station
```

The output shows that there are four groups that nodes assigned to each of them. For example, in the first group, there exist nodes **{0, 1, 2, 3, 5}**. Now, I want to colorize the nodes in each group with a specific color. (e.g. the nodes in the first group have the same color, blue). I am wondering if, how can I do that?

Also, my optimization variables are x[i,s] = 1, if operation i is being assigned to the station s, and y[s] = 1, if station s opened, otherwise zero.